# How to create a parent-independent control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating some kind of stage editor for my game in Windows Forms and I'm wondering if it's possible to create a control such as a PictureBox with its parent set to the screen - so with no parent at all. I'd need sth like this, becouse I allow users to click an item in a ListView which causes that a PictureBox is created on the stage and its location follows mouse cursor until the user clicks the mouse again. Drag and drop functionality doesn't suit me I guess becouse it requires the user to hold the mouse button all the time, right?

And the problem is that I assigned mouse move event handler to my main form but when mouse enters the area of the dragged PictureBox or any other control in this form, the PictureBox no longer changes position becouse the form loses its mouse focus.

Alternatively, maybe you could offer me some better solutions? Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Well you could make a `Form` with `BorderStyle=None` and `ShowInTaskbar=False` that contains your `PictureBox`.

Comment: @Jashaszun is right, I've done the same thing with labels to simulate dragging and dropping text entries from one control to another.

Comment: hmm I'll try this out and will respond if I managed to achieve my goal :)

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working but what about the background of the form? I would like it to have transparent background but it doesn't seem to be possible ;(. Such a line: MyDraggedForm.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Firebrick); causes exception that says it doesn't handle transparency

Comment: It is possible if you use the UpdateLayeredWindow API with PInvoke.

Comment: Oh actually I found a good solution on the transparent background:
MyForm.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
MyForm.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen; and it works like a charm ;). Thanks all!

Comment: TK is ok but alternatively you can simply set the form's size to the picturebox's size, can't you?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm setting backgroundImage property on this form instead of adding a PictureBox control to it. But I guess the background of the form would still be visible ;)